# How can I make a variable in Javascript that is accessible to all users?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am working on a continuously updated counter that shows how many seconds have passed, in total, during all users' visits to my website. If possible, use Javascript, but otherwise, let me know if a different language is required. Sorry, I do not have any code written yet to show, and this might be a stupid question, but I have searched everywhere and have not found a solution.

Comment: How do you intend to identify them on return visits?

Comment: The only way to do this is on the server. Javascript variables are local to each client, they aren't shared between different clients.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add up my seconds and Barmar's seconds and RobG's seconds together for how long we're on your page, or are you just trying to say "I launched my site at 8:14PM today and it has been 70 seconds since" ?  If you mean to show the second one, you could just have the time hardcoded into your javascript and have it display (updating every second on a timeout)

Comment: sova, I am trying to make the first option (finding the number of seconds that all users, not just the current one, have spent on my website). I should need to work with with the server. Websocket, as Sohel suggests, will probably work for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like websocket to show the seconds in realtime. Use a counter in the server and fire a ticker in every second. When the user visits your site, connect him with the socket and push the updates(number of seconds).

In this way, every user will get the time in realtime even he revisits your site.

If you are thinking for current session only and user specific, then you can do it easily using JavaScript. Search the web and there are lots of counter there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the system clock and a known start time. Have javascript grab the system clock's time then subtract the known start time to get the current elapsed time. Since the calculation is done when the page is rendered it'll always be accurate. And of course have a javascript timer continue ticking off from the calculated time after page render clock style.